# Can't use up arrow if the last message is deleted

Tags: bug, chat, keyboard

There is a weird bug in chat. Try this:

- Post a message, `M1`.
- Post another message, `M2`.
- Delete `M2`.
- Try hitting the up-arrow key.

I'd expect still to be able to navigate to `M1` to edit it, but it doesn't seem to work. But wait, there's more!

- Post another message, `M3`.
- Try hitting the up-arrow key.

Now it works again, but more importantly, *I can now navigate through the deleted message*. In fact, I can even try to edit the deleted message, although that edit will be rejected.

This behaviour seems inconsistent, and moreover a bit inconvenient, since **I have to use the mouse** if I want to edit `M1` in the first case. Just imagine the pain.

Comment: "just imagine the pain" - I feel you bro.

Comment: [It's worse now...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270471/unable-to-up-arrow-edit-beyond-deleted-message)