# Unable to up-arrow edit beyond deleted message

Tags: bug, edits, chat, keyboard-shortcuts

It used to be like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253162/cant-use-up-arrow-if-the-last-message-is-deleted) which wasn't too bad, but now if I up-arrow, I can go as far as a deleted message, but not further. Even if I post a message after the deleted message, I can go to that, but not further, it's like the removed message is a roadblock which is rather annoying, you should be able to up-arrow edit and it should just skip over the deleted messages instead of stopping you go beyond them.

Comment: I understand that this will be low priority, but it would be nice to fix it.

Comment: For me, the behaviour is still the same as before: if the last message is deleted, I can't use up-arrow. If there is an undeleted one afterwards, I can (and go through the deleted one, too). (Note: I have mod privileges in chat.)